Linux: Cannot ping interface while other interface is active
So I have a RHEL server which I plan to use for facility monitoring. It has 2 network interfaces on different subnets. For the sake of brevity these would be the result of an 'ifconfig' and I'll call them:

eno2 : 11.11.11.11/24 (DHCP, internet subnet)
eno3 : 22.22.22.22/24 (STATIC, infrastructure subnet)

Now my issue is as follows:
On the server itself I can ping the internet (8.8.8.8) and I can ping devices on the infrastructure subnet (22.22.22.201) with the correct interface being used for both (eno2 for 8.8.8.8 and eno3 for 22.22.22.201).
e.g
$ip route get 8.8.8.8
> 8.8.8.8 via 11.11.11.0 dev eno2 src 11.11.11.11 uid 0

$ip route get 22.22.22.201
> 22.22.22.201 dev eno3 src 22.22.22.22 uid 0

From my office computer (i.e remote) I can also reach devices on both of those subnets, but I cannot reach the server on it's own IP address (neither 11.11.11.11 nor 22.22.22.22) unless I turn one or the other interface off.
So from my remote (office pc), my ping towards the server look as follows:
# Both eno2 and eno3 active on server
ping 11.11.11.11 -t              ping 22.22.22.22 -t
Request timed out                Request timed out
Request timed out                Request timed out
Request timed out                Request timed out
...
# Turn off eno3
Reply from 11.11.11.11: bytes=32 Request timed out
Reply from 11.11.11.11: bytes=32 Request timed out  
Reply from 11.11.11.11: bytes=32 Request timed out  
Reply from 11.11.11.11: bytes=32 Request timed out  
Reply from 11.11.11.11: bytes=32 Request timed out
...
# Turn on eno3 (both on again)
Request timed out                Request timed out
Request timed out                Request timed out
Request timed out                Request timed out
Request timed out                Request timed out    
...
# Turn off eno2 
Request timed out                Reply from 22.22.22.22: bytes=32
Request timed out                Reply from 22.22.22.22: bytes=32
Request timed out                Reply from 22.22.22.22: bytes=32
Request timed out                Reply from 22.22.22.22: bytes=32
Request timed out                Reply from 22.22.22.22: bytes=32

This is NOT a firewall issue as the same happens with my firewall disabled:
$firewall-cmd --state
>not running

The same symptoms were reported here on a RHEL forum When RHEL has multiple IPs configured, only one is reachable from a remote network so I've implemented the solution for it by setting the rp_filter to 2 and the individual interfaces to 0 (no security). The result of my rp_filter for each interface is as follows:
#sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep "\.rp_filter"
>
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno2.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno3.rp_filter = 0


The output of my interface rules and table are as follows:
# ip -4 -br a ls
>
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 
eno3             UP             22.22.22.22/24 
eno2             UP             11.11.11.11/24 

IP Rules
# ip ru ls
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

IP Table
# ip -4 r ls table all
default via 11.11.11.1 dev eno2 proto dhcp src 11.11.11.11 metric 100 
default via 22.22.22.1 dev eno3 proto static metric 101 
22.22.22.0/24 dev eno3 proto kernel scope link src 22.22.22.22 metric 101 
11.11.11.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 11.11.11.11 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno3 scope link metric 1000 
local 22.22.22.22 dev eno3 table local proto kernel scope host src 22.22.22.22 
broadcast 22.22.22.255 dev eno3 table local proto kernel scope link src 22.22.22.22 
local 11.11.11.11 dev eno2 table local proto kernel scope host src 11.11.11.11 
broadcast 11.11.11.255 dev eno2 table local proto kernel scope link src 11.11.11.11 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1

And route -n for a summary of the above output:
root@APPSVR:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         11.11.11.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno2
0.0.0.0         22.22.22.1      0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eno3
22.22.22.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eno3
11.11.11.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno3

Yet the same issue persists where I can't reach either interface if both are active.
I have also made these changes persistent by writing them to the relevant config files (can't remember exactly where) and yes, I have rebooted the server.
Any help or alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I've spent about 3 days stuck on this issue now. Thanks in advance!

For some additional context, I reinstalled the OS and changed the boot system from UEFI to BIOS as well as trying balenaEtcher instead of Rufus for flashing the boot media. So we can also eliminate any installation or corrupt-packet related possibilities

Is the office pc in the same subnet with server? What the OS is installed on the office PC? Windows?

Also show the output of commands ip -4 -br a ls, ip ru ls and ip -4 r ls table all from the server.

@AntonDanilov The office pc itself is not in the same subnet, but attaches via a VPN to our core network through which we can access all the subnet (22.22.22.0/24) devices.

@Oom_Ben So it sounds like unless I turn one or the other interface off isn't exactly true, but really unless I turn eno2 off, and the reason is the server is assumed to use eno3 for traffics to any destination (i.e. no specific route is configured for e.g. the VPN clients; the default route is relied on for those hosts / destinations).

@TomYan I think you might be on to something, except I would think since ip route get 22.22.22.201 actually uses the eno3 interface that it would still be able to receive incoming traffic from anything on that gateway (22.22.22.1). Edit: Added output of route -n

@Oom_Ben Simple routing doesn't work like that. Even with policy routing, the gateway won't really be what's relevant (you can leverage connection marking based on which interface the connection-initating packet ingress the host through).

@TomYan so would that mean that the interface on which the connection is initiated (from outside) will then be used for that connection's traffic? That sounds like it could be the solution, how would I do that though?

@TomYan I was looking around at source/interface based routing and came across this post which basically answered my question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/reply-on-same-interface-as-incoming
I added the following rules:
echo 200 isp2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 22.22.22.22 table isp2 prio 1
ip route add default via 22.22.22.1 dev eno3 table isp2

Which solved my problem. For future users coming across this post, can you please provide a thorough explanation on why this rule is required (despite the output in route -n)

@TomYan also, thanks for the pointer! Please provide your explanation as an answer so that I can transfer bounty and accept the solution

Ok so I found the solution after some pointers from @TomYan.

Even with policy routing, the gateway won't really be what's relevant (you can leverage connection marking based on which interface the connection-initating packet ingress the host through).-TomYan

All my outbound traffic was going through the correct interfaces (as seen from the ip route get <IP> and route -n output) and this is what confused me as the inbound traffic is still expected to come through the default gateway (eno3) despite the outbound traffic being able to leave through either.
In order to have the correct gateway be used on inbound traffic I added an additional IP table and set up a rule and static route to the non-default second subnet (22.22.22.1).
This was done as follows:
Added a routing table called isp2 with ID 200
echo 200 isp2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

Added to that table the ip rule and static route to specify behaviour from the 22.22.22.0/24 subnet:
ip rule add from 22.22.22.22 table isp2 prio 1
ip route add default via 22.22.22.1 dev eno3 table isp2

That allowed me to reach both interfaces from the outside, but after a reboot I still had the same issue. So in order to make these changes persistent I did the following:
Create a script file /etc/network/if-up.d/static-routes with the following content:
#!/bin/sh

ip rule add from 22.22.22.22 table isp2 prio 1
ip route add default via 22.22.22.1 dev eno3 table isp2

Make it executable such that it will run whenever the interface comes up:
chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/static-routes

Now everything is working as expected and I can ping both interfaces from the outside and ping devices on both subnets from the server.
Hope this helps!

I had a problem similar to this with two network interfaces. The problem was caused my having gateways setup on both interfaces. Once we removed the internal(static) network gateway it worked as expected.
